# Changes made in Thread via ExecutorService not reflecting after execution

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have created a threadpool in Java with the help of ExecutorService and List of Futures.
I have created a RandomProcess class that implements Callable interface and overrides the call method
to perform certain operations.

It looks like this:

```
public class RandomProcess implements Callable<Integer> {
private Result result;

public RandomProcess(Result result) {
  super();
  this.result = result;
}

@Override
  public Integer call() throws Exception {
  //performSomeOps returns a Result that has certain values that I need
  result = performSomeOps();
  return 1;
}
```

I have this Result object in this class that is supposed to reflect the changes that were made
in the Randomprocess thread. unfortunately, the changes are not reflected when I return this Result.

```
public class Abc{
    public Result check(){
        Result result = new Result(true);
        try {
                ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(7);
                List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<?>>(7);
                for (Entity entity : randomListOfEntities) {
                    futures.add(exec.submit(new RandomProcess(result)));
                }
                for (Future<?> f : futures) {
                    f.get(); // wait for a process to complete
                }
                exec.shutdown();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Unable to figure out what the problem might be.

Comment: Why should it reflect anything? You are only overriding the internal reference to the `result` you aren't adding/chaning anything.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum Can you please tell how can the changes be retrieved that were made in the Result so that I have them in the check method. Thnx

Comment: How about **returning** the result instead of always returning 1? f.get() would then also return this result.

Comment: Either return the result, or update the values in the result... (Although with multiple threads, you never know which one will update to the final values).

Comment: Thanks guys, I updated the values in the result object after each call to the call method and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Line result = performSomeOps(); 
you are not updating the value inside result that is being passed while submitting thread. You are just assigning new object at that line instead of changing the original object. You need to update the value inside result object(Something link result.setSomevalue() = performSomeOps().getSomeValue()) or pass your result object to performSomeOps(), and update result inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

Need to Return "Result" as object from the "RandomProcess" Thread,Then Changes will be reflected.

public class RandomProcess implements Callable
{

```
private Result result;

public RandomProcess(Result result) {
  super();
  this.result = result;
}

@Override
public Result call() throws Exception {
     result = performSomeOps();
      return result;
}
```

}